# Condition: input:checked with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I would like to have a little help on an enigma that I have.
I have a button that changes according to the number of input:checked
but I would like to add a condition which is: select of the checkboxes of the same class.

for example can I have 2 or more input.

```html
<input class="banana" type="checkbox" value="Cavendish">
<input class="banana" type="checkbox" value="Goldfinger">
<input class="chocolato" type="checkbox" value="cocoa powder">
<input class="chocolato" type="checkbox" value="milk chocolate">
<input class="apple" type="checkbox" value="honneycrisp">
<input class="apple" type="checkbox" value="granny smith">
```

I can't use attribute name or value. it is not possible to modify the inputs.

the condition:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length >=2){

////////
  if (my classes are the same) {
    $('#btn').html("click me").prop('disabled', false);
} else {
 
$('#btn').html("too bad").prop('disabled', true);
}
//////

}
```

I try with

```
var checkClass = [];
        $.each($("input[type="checkbox"]:checked"), function() {
            checkClass.push($(this).attr('class'));
        });
```

I don't know if I'm going the right way or if I'm complicating the code but a little help would be welcome. For the moment my attempts have been unsuccessful.

Comment: I don't understand the logic: you want to make disabled elements checked if they are not of the same class of the one which is clicked, and leave it checked in you any way?

Comment: I thought I was relatively clear. 
You have to imagine that the list is much longer.
I have to select objects of the same class.
if what i select have the same class then i can click on the button otherwise the button is disabled. or vice versa
if I select objects of different classes then the button remains disabled otherwise it is possible to click on it.

Comment: I assume `.htm(...)` is supposed to be `.html(...)`

Comment: it would make more sense to use a data attribute and not a class for this.

Comment: oops sorry for forgetting it's ".html". i'm going to dig on the data attribute side too. it's cool to have different vision of things! thanks to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function will reference the first checkbox that's checked `className` and enable each checkbox that has said `className` whilst disabling all other checkboxes. Details are commented in Snippet.

```js
// All checkboxes
const all = $(':checkbox');
// Any change event on any checkbox run function `matchCategory`
all.on('change', matchCategory);

function matchCategory() {
  // All checked checkboxes
  const checked = $(':checkbox:checked');
  let category;
  // if there is at least one checkbox checked...
  if (checked.length > 0) {
    // ...enable (.btn)...
    $('.btn').removeClass('off');
    // ...get the class of the first checked checkbox...
    category = checked[0].className;
    // ...disable ALL checkboxes...
    all.attr('disabled', true);
    // ...go through each checkbox...
    all.each(function() {
      // if THIS checkbox has the class defined as (category)...
      if ($(this).is('.' + category)) {
        // ...enable it
        $(this).attr('disabled', false);
        // Otherwise...  
      } else {
        // ...disable and uncheck it  
        $(this).attr('disabled', true).prop('checked', false);
      }
    });
    // Otherwise...
  } else {
    // ...enable ALL checkboxes...
    all.attr('disabled', false);
    // ...disable (.btn)
    $('.btn').addClass('off');
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.off {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<input class="beverage" type="checkbox" value="Alcohol">
<label></label><br>
<input class="beverage" type="checkbox" value="Coffee">
<label>☕</label><br>
<input class="dessert" type="checkbox" value="cake">
<label></label><br>
<input class="dessert" type="checkbox" value="Ice Cream">
<label></label><br>
<input class="appetizer" type="checkbox" value="Salad">
<label></label><br>
<input class="appetizer" type="checkbox" value="Bread">
<label></label><br>
<button class='btn off' type='button '>Order</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Your solutions are great. it's better than what I had in mind!

Answer (score 1):

some thing like that ?

```js
const 
   bt_restart = document.getElementById('bt-restart')
 , chkbx_all  = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')
 ;
var checked_class = ''
  ;
bt_restart.onclick = _ =>
  {
  checked_class = ''
  chkbx_all.forEach(cbx=>
    {
    cbx.checked=cbx.disabled=false
    cbx.closest('label').style = '' 
    })
  }
chkbx_all.forEach(cbx=>
  {
  cbx.onclick = e => 
    {
    if (checked_class === '')  checked_class = cbx.className 
    else if (checked_class != cbx.className  )
      {
      cbx.checked = false
      cbx.disabled = true
      cbx.closest('label').style = 'color: grey' 
      }
    }  
  })
```

```html
<button id="bt-restart">restart</button>  <br> <br>

 <label>  <input class="banana"    type="checkbox" value="Cavendish"     > a-Cavendish      </label> <br>
 <label>  <input class="banana"    type="checkbox" value="Goldfinger"    > a-Goldfinger     </label> <br>
 <label>  <input class="chocolato" type="checkbox" value="cocoa powder"  > b-cocoa powder   </label> <br>
 <label>  <input class="chocolato" type="checkbox" value="milk chocolate"> b-milk chocolate </label> <br>
 <label>  <input class="apple"     type="checkbox" value="honneycrisp"   > c-honneycrisp    </label> <br>
 <label>  <input class="apple"     type="checkbox" value="granny smith"  > c-granny smith   </label> <br>
```

Comment: oh that's a good idea! I hadn't thought of that solution. 
thanks for your help. I'll try to adapt this.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it's like a [Matching Pairs card game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_(card_game))

this answer is without global checked_group variable, and respecting **epascarello** message about [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) [see also](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) usage.
Adding  a repentance on uncheck elements

```js
const 
   bt_restart = document.getElementById('bt-restart')
 , chkbx_all  = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')
 ;
function clearGame()
  {
  chkbx_all.forEach(cbx=>
    {
    cbx.checked = cbx.disabled = false
    cbx.closest('label').style = '' 
    })
  }
bt_restart.onclick = clearGame

chkbx_all.forEach(cbx=>
  {
  cbx.onclick = e => 
    {
    let checkedList = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')  
    if (cbx.checked)
      {
      let checked_group = ''
      checkedList.forEach(cEl=>{ if (cEl !== cbx) checked_group = cEl.dataset.group })
      
      if (checked_group === '')  checked_group = cbx.dataset.group 
      else if (checked_group !== cbx.dataset.group  )
        {
        cbx.checked = false  // you need to uncheck wrong group checkboxes for preserving checkedList
        cbx.disabled = true
        cbx.closest('label').style = 'color: grey' 
        }
      }
    else if (checkedList.length === 0)  // case of cheked repentir
      clearGame()
    }  
  })
```

```html
<button id="bt-restart">restart</button>  <br> <br>

 <label>  <input data-group="banana"    type="checkbox" value="Cavendish"     > a-Cavendish      </label> <br>
 <label>  <input data-group="banana"    type="checkbox" value="Goldfinger"    > a-Goldfinger     </label> <br>
 <label>  <input data-group="chocolato" type="checkbox" value="cocoa powder"  > b-cocoa powder   </label> <br>
 <label>  <input data-group="chocolato" type="checkbox" value="milk chocolate"> b-milk chocolate </label> <br>
 <label>  <input data-group="apple"     type="checkbox" value="honneycrisp"   > c-honneycrisp    </label> <br>
 <label>  <input data-group="apple"     type="checkbox" value="granny smith"  > c-granny smith   </label> <br>
```